# Google Script: Decode Hebrew into readable text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, decode

I have the string "`%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%AA`" that needs to translate into something like "`הרשות לפיתוח הנגב`" (a simple google search returns it as a first option)

The question is how to get the proper Hebrew spelling via Apps script or something BigQuery built-in.
I've searched around for a while and have not found anything yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample of how to do this in BigQuery by going from hex codes to bytes to string:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION UnescapeString(str STRING) AS (
  (SELECT CAST(STRING_AGG(CODE_POINTS_TO_BYTES([CAST(CONCAT('0x', c) AS INT64)]), b'') AS STRING)
   FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(str, '%')) AS c
   WHERE c != '')
);

WITH Input AS (
  SELECT "%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%AA" AS str
)
SELECT str, UnescapeString(str) AS unescaped_str
FROM Input;
```

The output for the `unescaped_str` column is `אפרת`.

Comment: Great,  I was wondering if anyone could provide the same solution for GAS. I've been goofing around with the Utilities service, but it fails to decode ASCII string every single time.